# Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: nltokenizer

I am trying to instal Questgen.ai (https://github.com/ramsrigouthamg/Questgen.ai) on my MacOS 11.6.  One of the requirements is transformers 3.0.2.  When running `pip3 install transformers==3.0.2`, I get this error:
`Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully` + a lot of text.

I looked around and found:

- Install Rust `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`
- Restart terminal
- Install transformers again

This did not work for me.

Can someone help ? (I use Python 3.9.1)

Comment: ` + a lot of text.` -- this text includes the error. Can you include it?

`This did not work for me.` Why not? What happened? Can you include the relevant error messages?

Comment: Had you resolved this problem?